# .NET Core: HttpClientFactory: How to configure ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler without dependency injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, httpclient

I have a .NET Core class library. Am creating HttpClient instance using IHttpClientFactory without dependency injection. I have included Microsoft DI nuget package in my class library.

Sample Code #1:

```
Class A {

private readonly HttpClient client;

 public A(){
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection().AddHttpClient().BuildServiceProvider();
            var _httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
            client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();  //HttpClient instance created
            //TODO: Add custom message handler without DI.
  }
}
```

Using DI, we can configure custom message handlers:
Sample code #2 with DI:

```
services.AddHttpClient()

    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        return new HttpClientHandler
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (m, crt, chn, e) => true
        };
    });
```

I want to add HttpClientHandler to my Sample code #1 without DI.
How to configure primary message handler without DI?

Comment: you mean without using the AddHttpClient?

Comment: you can always get the `HttpClient` out of the `services` using `services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<HttpClient>()`

Comment: Am able to get HttpClient.
i want to add custom message handler.

Comment: if you use the above function, your message handler would be in it. You can also use `AddHttpMessageHandler` to add additional message handlers

Comment: Good example. In your example, "services" variable is of type IServiceCollection which is from DI container. I want to add the handler in a class library which does not have DI container

Comment: do you mean you don't want your library to contain the Microsoft.DependencyInjection.Extensions nuget included in it?

Comment: You will have to implement `IHttpClientFactory`. It only has one method, `CreateClient(string name)`, so that's not bad, but it seems to negate the benefits of using it because the benefit is how it interacts with DI and the builder API, both of which require an IOC abstraction.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane library can contain DI Extensions. But I did not want to inject dependencies via DI container. The answer in this thread solved my problem.

Comment: @AluanHaddad ofcourse DI gives lot more flexibility since .NET core framework recommends it. Setting up DI Container was not necessary in my case since the usage of HttpClient is in only one class.

Comment: That wasn't what I was getting at. I did not mean that you need DI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's a weird setup that you have, but apart from that, you can probably do something like this:

```
private readonly HttpClient client;

public A() {
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddHttpClient("YourHttpClientName")
        .Configure<HttpClientFactoryOptions>("YourHttpClientName", options =>
            options.HttpMessageHandlerBuilderActions.Add(builder =>
                builder.PrimaryHandler = new HttpClientHandler
                {
                    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (m, crt, chn, e) => true
                }))
        .BuildServiceProvider();
    var _httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
    client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();  //HttpClient instance created
    //TODO: Add custom message handler without DI.
}
```

I just checked the implementation of `ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler` and chained it into your setup.

---

My suggestion would be to change your code and properly use DI, as .NET Core heavily relies on this.

Comment: this is cool. thanks for the solution. Ofcourse .NET Core service rely on DI, in my current scenario DI would result in a redesign. So I had only one use case of using HttpClientFactory without DI.